# React inactivity warning since last api request using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've developed a React application that utilizes axios for communicating with RESTful APIs. My objective is to notify the user when their "session" is about to expire. In this context, the "session" refers to the duration since the most recent API request. To address this concern across all API requests, I'm contemplating the implementation of an axios request interceptor.
But the problem is, how do I synchronize it with a react component?
I was thinking of setting a variable in the session storage from the interceptor, but how do I check for its updates from inside a component? I have read about `window.addEventListener("storage"...)` but it works for events triggered from another window.
Another idea is defining the interceptor inside a useEffect, similar to this:

```js
  const [idle, setIdle] = useState(false);
  const timer = useRef<number | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        if (timer.current) {
          clearTimeout(timer.current);
        }
        setIdle(false);
        timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
          setIdle(true);
        }, 10000);
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

but this would not work with multiple tabs.

Any ideas?